# select tag inside ons-col hides other ons-cols

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

Below is the code where, without the select tab, all works fine. The moment i add the select tag, all other ons-col is not rendered.

Even tried by changing the order of the column, then all previous columns are rendered.

This seems to trivial, but has gone beyond me.

```html
<ons-row class="row" ng-repeat="deal in trickNowData" >
        <ons-col width="30%" class="col" style="-webkit-box-flex: 0; flex: 0 0 30%; max-width: 30%;">
          <div class="TN-table TN-table-content">
            <div class="TN-deal-name">{{deal.DealName}}</div>
            <div class="TN-deal-type">{{deal.DealType}}</div>
            <div class="TN-deal-calc">{{deal.ActualValue}}/- for {{deal.People}} people</div>
          </div>
        </ons-col>

        <ons-col width="20%" class="col" align="center" style="-webkit-box-flex: 0; flex: 0 0 15%; max-width: 15%;">
          <div class="TN-table TN-table-content">
            <div class="TN-deal-people">{{deal.People}}</div>
            <div ng-if="onsenDone" class="TN-deal-people"><select ng-options="item.value for item in dropDown.people" ng-model="selected.people"></div>
            <!-- <div ></div> -->
          </div>
        </ons-col>

        <ons-col width="45%" class="col" align="center" style="-webkit-box-flex: 0; flex: 0 0 45%; max-width: 45%;">
          <div class="TN-table TN-table-content">
            <i class="ion-minus-round TN-up-down"></i>
            <span class="TN-deal-value">{{deal.DealValue}}</span>
            <i class="ion-plus-round TN-up-down"></i>
          </div>
        </ons-col>

        <ons-col class="col" align="center">
          <div class="TN-table TN-table-content">
            <i class="ion-trash-a TN-delete"></i>
          </div>
        </ons-col>

      </ons-row>
```

Comment: Try closing the div with `</select>. If that doesn't work, please post a codepen example with this problem :)

Comment: True, that solved it. That did take a lot of time to debug. Thanks a lot.